# Javascript Sorting Matrix Diagonally

Tags: javascript

There is an algorithm question asking to sort a matrix diagonally. I'm not finding a solution for this quesiton.

```
const matrix = 
[ 
  [1, 3, 9, 4],
  [9, 5, 7, 7],
  [3, 6, 9, 7],
  [1, 2, 2, 2]
]
```

Should output:

```
[
  [1, 9, 9, 7],
  [3, 5, 6, 9],
  [3, 4, 7, 7],
  [1, 2, 2, 2]
]
```

My code so far:

```
function diagonalSort(matrix) {
  const cols = matrix[0].length;
  const rows = matrix.length;
  const maxLength = Math.max(cols, rows);
  let temp;

  for (let k = 0; k <= 2 * (maxLength - 1); k++) {
    temp = [];
    for (let y = cols - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
      let x = k - y;
      // console.log(k, y, x);
      if (x >= 0 && x < rows) {
        temp.push(matrix[y][x]);
      }
    }
    if (temp.length > 0) {
      console.log(temp);
    }
  }
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
[ 1 ]
[ 3, 9 ]
[ 3, 5, 9 ]
[ 1, 4, 6, 7 ]
[ 2, 7, 9 ]
[ 2, 7 ]
[ 2 ]
```

But how to put it back together...?

Comment: Please show your own attempts, especially for a homework exercise.

Comment: Its not homework, this is from CodeSignal's algorithm challenges. I don't have a solution beyond the answer linked.

Comment: Ok, but remember that SO is not a coding service.  The expectation is that you post what you've tried and where you get stuck.

Comment: btw, CodeSignal on their main page claim that they use Plagiarism Checker

Comment: I'm not taking an actual test yet, just solving their algorithms that anyone can go try to solve. I absolutely suck at matrix's so I'm asking here. Also added my code so far.

Comment: @RizaKhan Matrices (as in mathematics) and arrays in programming are very different things.

Comment: Haha fair enough. How about Arrays in Array?

Comment: Can you explain what "diagonal sort" is meant to be? I'm looking at your "should output" table and I don't see how it's sorted or what the pattern is.

Comment: @Dai: It took me a while to see it.  We want to sort in place each of the southwest -> northeast diagonals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach is also a gentle introduction to functional lenses in Javascript:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => [...Array (hi - lo)] .map ((_, i) => i + lo)

const diagonals = (rows, cols) => 
  range (0, rows + cols - 1) .map (
    d => range (Math.max (d - rows + 1, 0), Math.min (d, cols - 1) + 1) 
         .map (x => [d - x, x])
  )

const coordLens = (coords) => ({
  get: (m) => coords .map (([x, y]) => m [x] [y]),
  set: (arr, m) => coords .reduce (
    (m, [x, y], i) =>  {m [x] [y] = arr [i]; return m},
    m .map (r => [... r]) // cheap clone
  ),
})

const diagonalLenses = (rows, cols) =>
  diagonals (rows, cols) .map (coordLens)

const sortMatrix = (comparator) => (m) =>
  diagonalLenses (m.length, m[0].length) 
    .reduce ((m, lens) => lens.set (lens .get (m) .sort (comparator), m), m)

const numericSorter = (a, b) => a - b

console .log (
  sortMatrix (numericSorter) ([ 
    [1, 3, 9, 4],
    [9, 5, 7, 7],
    [3, 6, 9, 7],
    [1, 2, 2, 2]
  ])
  .map (r => r .join (' ')) .join ('\n')
)
```

After the minor helper function `range` (which works like `range (3. 12) ==> [3, 4 , 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`) (including the start, excluding the stop) we have `diagonals`, which calculates the diagonals as arrays of `[x, y]` pairs, given the height and width of a matrix.

The most important bit here is `coordLens`.  A `lens` is a glorified getter/setter pair for some facet of a data structure.  They turn out to be quite useful.  Many of the standard introductions to them point to a single property or array index, or perhaps a nested path inside an object.  These are slightly more interesting.  `coordLens` takes an array of `[x, y]` coordinates and returns a lens that we can use to extract the values at those coordinates from a given matrix, or to set the values in (a copy of) a matrix from elements supplied as an array.

On top of these two we build `diagonalLenses`, which takes the number of rows and columns and creates an array of coordinate lenses, one for each diagonal.

We build the main function `sortMatrix` on these functions.  We accept a standard comparator and return a function that takes a matrix and returns another of the same shape, with each of the southwest -> northeast diagonals sorted.  We create an array of lenses using `diagonalLenses`.  Then for each lens, we `get` the values, sort them and use the `set` method to update our cloned matrix with the sorted values.

Note that there is little error-checking in any of this.  The pieces will work together in the manner described here, but `coordLens` should, if used more generically, check that the array values it's trying to receive or to set are within bounds.

### Addendum - the use of lenses

I originally wanted to explain the use of lenses in greater depth.  But it was bedtime and I left it with just a brief description.  There are [many tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Functional+Lenses+Javascript&ia=web) available to cover the basics.  But very, very briefly, lenses are structures that focus on one aspect of a data structure.  You create one by supplying a getter and a setter for your aspect, and then you can use a consistent interface to read, write, and modify data.  (In the write/modify cases, this would involve creating a copy of the object.  There's no mutation involved; we're not barbarians!)

What I am taking advantage of here is that the lenses don't have to be as simple as tends to be shown in those tutorials.  Instead of pointing to a single property of an object, they can do more.  One of my favorite examples is that a weather app which -- as is only sensible -- reports temperatures in Celsius, but which has users who live in a benighted country like by own, who only know Fahrenheit.

```js
const fahrenLens = lens(
  obj => obj.temp * 9 / 5 + 32,
  (degF, obj) => ({...obj, temp: (degF - 32) * 5 / 9})
)
```

And it can be used like this:

```js
const nyc= {name: 'New York', lat: 40.730610, lng: -73.935242, temp: 25}

view (fahrenLens, nyc) //=> 77
set (fahrenLens, 86, nyc) 
//=> {name: "New York", lat: 40.73061, lng: -73.935242, temp: 30}
over (fahrenLens, t => t - 27, nyc) 
//=> {name: "New York", lat: 40.73061, lng: -73.935242, temp: 10}
```

This uses three standard function for working with lenses, which, in our simple lens implementation might look like this:

```js
const view = (lens, o) => lens .get (o)
const set = (lens, v, o) => lens .set (v, o)
const over = (lens, f, o) => lens .set (f (lens .get (o)), o)
```

In the answer above we use lenses to track multiple coordinates in an *m x n* grid, using this code:

```js
const coordLens = (coords) => ({
  get: (m) => coords .map (([x, y]) => m [x] [y]),
  set: (arr, m) => coords .reduce (
    (m, [x, y], i) =>  {m [x] [y] = arr [i]; return m},
    m .map (r => [... r]) // cheap clone
  ),
})
```

Given a set of coordinates, when we `view` a matrix through this coordinate lens, we get back an array of the values at those coordinates.  When we `set` the `matrix` with an array of values through this lens, we fold the array of values into a new matrix by setting each coordinate to the corresponding array value, starting with a copy of the matrix.

Using `diagonalLenses`, we create an array of coordinate lenses, one for each diagonal in the grid.  (Here considering only on *southwest -> northeast* diagonals.)  If we were to use our `over` function we could simplify further to

```js
const sortMatrix = (comparator) => (m) =>
  diagonalLenses (m) 
    .reduce ((m, lens) =>  over (lens, xs => xs.sort (comparator), m), m)
```

And my own preference would be to introduce a `sort` function like

```js
const sort = (comparator) => (xs) => [...xs] .sort (comparator)
```

which would allow us to simplify that further to

```js
const sortMatrix = (comparator) => (m) =>
  diagonalLenses (m) 
    .reduce ((m, lens) =>  over (lens, sort (comparator), m), m)
```

Now a good question is how much this abstraction buys us.  Using the same `range` and `diagonals` functions, we could write `sortMatrix` like this:

```js
const sortMatrix = (comparator) => (m) =>
  diagonals (m) 
    .reduce (
      (m, diagonal) => {
        const vals = diagonal .map (([y, x]) => m [y] [x]) .sort (comparator)
        return diagonal .reduce ((m, [y, x], i) => {m [y] [x] = vals [i]; return m}, m)
      },
      m .map (r => [...r])
    )
```

which involves fewer lines of code than the combination of `coordLens`, `diagLenses`, and even our shortest earlier version of `sortMatrix`.

One argument is that it adds nothing, that this version is fine.  If you have to do nothing else with those diagonals, or with other collections of coordinates, this might be true.  But these lenses can be very convenient.  If we wanted to total up each diagonal for some reason, it's a one-liner on top of the response from `diagonalLenses`:

```js
const m = [ 
  [1, 3, 9, 4],
  [9, 5, 7, 7],
  [3, 6, 9, 7],
  [1, 2, 2, 2]
]

const myDiagonals = diagonalLenses (m .length, m [0] .length) 
const diagonalSums = myDiagonals .map (d => sum (view2 (d, m)))

diagonalSums // => [1, 12, 17, 18, 18, 9, 2]
```

for an obvious `sum` function over an array.

And there are many more things we could do with them.

One thing that I should make clear is that these lenses we create are not specific to a particular matrix.  Our list of diagonal lenses for one *m x n* matrix are exactly the same for another *m x n* one.

And the same is true for the underlying coordinate lenses.  They have to do only with the shape of the matrix.  We can easily imagine a sudoku solver which has a lens for each row, column, and box, which we then test for a correct solution with something like

```js
const gridCompleted = (grid) => 
  lenses .every (lens => completeGroup (view (lens, grid)))
```

Comment: What is this syntax called: `sortMatrix(numericSorter)(matrix)` I've never seen that before

Comment: @RizaKhan: I don't know a name for it.  `sortMatrix` takes a comparator  and returns a function.  That returned function takes a matrix and returns a new matrix.  So I guess you can say that, `sortMatrix` is a *curried* function to which we *partially apply* the comparator.  This is very common in functional programming.

Comment: @RizaKhan: I should add that one reason for this style is that we can now create reusable functions with the comparator included: `const sortDiagonalsNumerically = sortMatrix ((a, b) => a - b)` or `const sortDiagonalsAlphabetically = sortMatrix ((a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0)`.  Then you can use that function when you need to.  This may or may not be important for your use of this function, but the flexibility is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```js
    function* enumerateDiagonals(xLength, yLength) {
        
        for (let y = 0; y < yLength; y++) {
            yield {
                x: 0,
                y: y
            };
        }
        
        for (let x = 1; x < xLength; x++) {
            yield {
                x: x,
                y: yLength - 1
            };
        }
    }

    function sliceMatrix(matrix, diagonal) {
        const slice = [];
        
        for (let y = diagonal.y, x = diagonal.x; y >=0 && x<matrix[y].length ; y--, x++) {
            slice.push(matrix[y][x])
        }
        
        return slice
    }

    function emplaceIntoMatrix(slice, matrix, diagonal) {
        
        for (let i=0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            matrix[diagonal.y - i][diagonal.x + i] = slice[i];
        }
        
    }


    const matrix = 
    [ 
      [1, 3, 9, 4],
      [9, 5, 7, 7],
      [3, 6, 9, 7],
      [1, 2, 2, 2]
    ];

    const Ylength = matrix.length
    const Xlength = matrix[0].length

    console.log(Ylength)
    console.log(Xlength)

    const sortedMatrix = [ ];
    for(let i=0; i<Ylength; i++) {
        sortedMatrix[i] = new Array(Xlength);
    }

    for (const diagonal of enumerateDiagonals(Xlength, Ylength)) {
        
        var slice = sliceMatrix(matrix, diagonal);
        slice.sort();
        
        emplaceIntoMatrix(slice, sortedMatrix, diagonal);
    }

    console.log(sortedMatrix);
```

Comment: Its legit, just complicated as heck. I never seen that function* and thats another rabbit hole you opened up for me so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
const cols = matrix[0].length;
const rows = matrix.length;
const maxLength = Math.max(cols, rows);
let tempArr = [];
let result = [];

for (let k = 0; k <= 2 * (maxLength - 1); k++) {
    let temp = [];
    for (let y = cols - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
        let x = k - y;
        // console.log(k, y, x);
        if (x >= 0 && x < rows) {
            temp.push(matrix[y][x]);
        }
    }

    if (temp.length > 0) {
        // console.log(temp.sort());
        tempArr.push(temp.sort());
    }
}

for (let k = 0; k <= maxLength - 1; k++) {
    let tempResult = [];
    let arr = tempArr.filter((a) => a.length > 0);
    // console.log(arr);
    for (let i = 0; i <= maxLength - 1; i++) {
        const length = arr[i].length;
        tempResult.push(arr[i][length - 1]);
        tempArr[tempArr.indexOf(arr[i])].pop();
    }
    result.push(tempResult);
}
return result;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.